# .Net Winform Diagram Library

Tags: .net, diagram

I'm looking for a library to create and manipulate diagrams. Something with the look and feel of VS DataSet or the SSMS Diagram would be perfect, but I'm not expecting that much. The features I would need would be :

- Creation of "Groups of item"
- Drag & Dropping of items
- Creating links between items of different groups

I would use this library in WinForms and I plan to code in C#, even though any .Net library would do. Ideas anyone?

Comment: Try Nevron Diagram for .NET:
https://www.nevron.com/products-dot-net-diagram-overview.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured I'd add another answer.

This library is not free, but it seems to be exactly what you described: http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/windows-forms/Diagram

This one doesn't look as good but is free: http://www.dalssoft.com/diagram/screenshots.aspx

This article uses a control like you describe, so maybe you can use that: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AutoDiagrammer.aspx

Hope that's better.

Comment: I've seen the one from Dalssoft and it looked a lot like visio, but I haven't seen the two others before. I just checked the websites and both looks quite interesting, and I even think AutoDiagrammer is the best one. I'll accept your answer since it's plenty of alternatives and I'll add some other comments later this week when I'll check them out, just to tell which I used and what I liked about it. Thanks again Jouke!

Comment: @TipX - Looks like dalssoft does not exist anymore.  I am looking for a similar diagramming tool.  +1 for the question.  Does AutoDiagrammer support drag drop?  Can't see anything about it on the page

Answer (score 0):

One more possible contender in a commercial scenario is [yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/yfiles.net).

In contrast to most of the other suggestions here (at the time of writing), it actually supports what the OP is asking for: "Groups of Items" are supported on various levels. You can group elements so that they behave the same way, but more importantly you can group them into a visual hierarchy (I think this is what the OP was looking for), so that you get container nodes that contain arbitrary other nodes at any nesting level. Dragging and dropping of items of course is supported, too, as well as creating links between any nodes in the diagram, no matter at what grouping level these items reside and also between the groups themselves:

[image: Nested groups of nodes.]

<sup>*Full disclosure*: 
I work for the company that creates that library, but on SO/SE I do not represent my employer. My comments, thoughts, and posts are my own.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Try these: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

Made by Microsoft themselves. I have had good experiences with this in the past.

Comment: I stumbled on these earlier, but by their name, and what's written on the page, I taught they were only charts, not diagrams.

Comment: I thought they did both. I recall they're really flexible.

Comment: Nop, I just checked out and I can't do Diagrams with MSCharts, sadly. Thanks though! :-D